# Why my script has the same duration when using CPU and using GPU?

Tags: tensorflow

I use Google Cloud Platform with Ubuntu 16.04, Cuda 9, Tensorflow with GPU 1.8

I do a gradient descent using the Adam Optimizer for 100 iterations on a function of 5 variables that is roughly a sum of 100 terms of sigmoid functions.
It takes 6-7s using a GPU K80 and it takes the same time using the CPU !

I know it's really using the GPU (or the CPU) because I print the device used for the operations so my script yield logging similar to:

`add_5/x: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0` when using the GPU and

`add_5/x: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0` when using the CPU

Why does it take the same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPUs are not always faster than CPUs. Without seeing a profiler output it's hard to say what's going on here. Is your model numerically intensive in a way that batches well (i.e. does it have lots of matmuls or convolutions)? If so, GPUs should speed you up, but they are not magic.